# Meaning of "our findings could be reproduced" in a scientific paper

Tags: phrase-meaning, modal-verbs

From *The basis for folinic acid treatment in neuro-psychiatric disorders* (Ramaekers et al., 2016):

> In the latter group of low-functioning autism our studies identified a prevalence of blocking FR autoantibodies between 55 - 59%. Our findings **could be reproduced** by Frye et al, who identified blocking type FRα autoantibodies at a rate of 60% in children with ASD (38).

What is the meaning of **could be reproduced**? "They have probably been reproduced, but we are not sure"?

Upon reading this sentence for the first time, I imagined "could" to mean "they could reproduce it in the future", until I had read to the end of the sentence and saw the [38] footnote, meaning that the findings **have been** reproduced.

Is this a correct use of the modal **could**? Shouldn't it be **could have been reproduced** instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that is certainly odd wording. If the other study did show the same thing, it would be "is reproduced". If the other study had the potential to do it, but didn't, it would "could have been reproduced". This doesn't fit either situation... but there's a third possibility. How plausible this is depends on some subject-specific stuff, so I'm not 100% sure.

It could be that the other study (Fry et al.) has produced some data that suggests that, once the data has been fully analysed, might reproduce their results. That would make sense if finding "blocking type FRα autoantibodies at a rate of 60% in children with ASD" resembles just *part of* the key results of the paper this is quoted from.

Comment: At first reading I thought the same, but consider “I did it and my sister could do it to.” I have a feeling this is a common way to word reproducibility in papers, which is why it seems odd to us.

Comment: Eh... I did have some time working with medical research in a previous role (as a patient member on a guideline development committee), and I don't remember this form of words. All the uses I found on a Google search were reasonably clearly hypothetical or in the form "showed that X could be reproduced by".

Comment: Interesting. I will have to dig more when I have time.

Answer (score 0):

To reproduce findings means if you do the study again, the same results or outcome would be had.

could be reproduced is right. Frye et al was able to reproduce them.

could have been reproduced would introduce doubt and suggest that Frye et al either did not reproduce them or could not reproduce them.

- My ideas could be reproduced by my colleagues. [They gave the test and got the same results: they were able to do it.]
- My ideas could have been reproduced by my colleagues. [They gave the test and didn't reproduce them but could have: the possibility was there.]

Comment: It seems weird that they didn’t write “were reproduced”, doesn’t it? Does it imply to you that maybe the study was conducted as a follow-on to confirm the other?

Comment: It is not exactly the same thing, though. If the expectation was low and it turned out positively,then, I understand the use of "could be reproduced" here.

Comment: @ColleenV *Could be reproduced* here simply means *were capable of being reproduced*. It was very likely proven that they *could* be reproduced because they *were* reproduced (proving it empirically), but that's a subtly different meaning. (However, nobody would assume that both things aren't meant.)

Comment: @JasonBassford That is what I thought I had said. :)

Answer (score 0):

> could be reproduced

is bad wording, no matter how you look at it.

If they **actually reproduced** it, the fragment should have read:

> were reproduced

However, if they did **not reproduce**, the fragment should have read:

> were not reproduced

Different other situations are possible with regard to what happened, but **could be reproduced** is too ambiguous for a scientific paper.

Of course, the intended meaning is "were reproduced", but the confusion is still confusion.

On the conspiratorial side of the things, we can understand the following: "Frye et al tried to reproduced the results, they maybe had some success, but also something was wrong. So instead of specifying failure explicitely, we use an ambiguous sentence hinting success".